# How to log exception to MS SQL database using MS Enterprise Library?

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

I already logged thrown exceptions to text file , now i want to log them to MS Sql database 
but i couldn't find clear sample to perform this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure a `DatabaseTraceListener`.

Comment: I already do that but what is required database tables and procedure

Comment: You can find the scripts under `C:\EntLib4Src\Blocks\Logging\Src\DatabaseTraceListener\Scripts`.